# How to show if a subset of the vector space P (all polynomials) is a vector space, specifically, P2(0)=P(1)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have already read this link [Prove: The set of all polynomials p with p(2) = p(3) is a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201502/prove-the-set-of-all-polynomials-p-with-p2-p3-is-a-vector-space)
But am still confused. I understand that there is a zero vector in this set as 2P(0)-P(1)=0, but how do I prove closed addition? This is what I attempted:

2P(0)-P(1)=0
and (2P(0)-P(1))-(2P(0)-P(1)=0 therefore is is a vector space.
This kind of makes sense to me but I am unsure if I am understanding the concepts correctly.

Could someone also give me an example of a subset that is not a vector space because it does not have a zero vector in it?

Comment: For your last question consider the subset $P_0$ of $P$ such that $p(0)=2$ for all $p \in P_0$.

Comment: For the last question: $\{ p \in P : p(0) = 1 \}$.  (And an example where zero is in the subset but it's not closed under addition: $\{ p \in P : p(2) = p(0) p(1) \}$.)